# Graph API GetAccessTokenForUserAsync & scopes

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to use the graph api to eventual create teams and add users. Having issues with the getting the access token

with the code below:

```
scopes = new[] { GraphConstants.UserRead };
await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
```

after the initial login I get the following screen:
[image]

I am only requesting UserRead scopes. Not sure why it is asking for "read & write groups", "read & write all user profiles",etc. show in above screenshot.

My app in azure is also configured for User Read.
[image]

I have been using this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/tree/main/) for reference.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Either the user will have to consent, or if you or someone on your team has the elevated priviledges, they can Grant Admin Consent for everyone in the tenant via Azure. See the greyed out option in your last screenshot. Once consent is granted, that popup will go away.

Comment: Thanks. I will have IT grant admin consent.

Comment: The sample you are mentioning DOES ask for the User.ReadWrite.All and Group.ReadWrite.All (in the attributes of the API methods). If did not asked for this, you woudln't get this prompt

Comment: Here is the document for reference which mentions the required permissions includes:"User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions